# Website unaccessible from mobile data

Tags: apache-http-server, mobile-phone

I created a [personal website](https://thibautvoirand.com/) containing simple pages based on HTML/CSS, which I am hosting on a VPS with Ubuntu and apache.

I can't access the website from mobile using cellular data (I can access when connected to Wifi).

My website successfully passes the [Google mobile usability report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9063469?hl=en).

I also successfully access the default apache page when browsing my [VPS IP](https://51.68.188.186/) from mobile.

I have no clue on how to debug this. Is there any typical issue that I might have missed to allow access from mobile?

I would be happy to give more details on my configuration that could help pinpointing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't access my website because there was an error in the IPv6 address indicated in the DNS zone for my web domain and IPv6 wasn't configure on my VPS.

I entered my VPS' IPv6 address in my domain DNS zone using my registrar's client interface.

I configured IPv6 by following this guide: https://docs.ovh.com/fr/dedicated/network-ipv6/#ubuntu-2110-et-2204_1

And the site is now accessible through IPv6 and mobile.